# How to pass variableized expressions to .FindAll()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, delegates

{High level}, I am trying to post back an ASP.NET MVC view which has multiple 'user inputs' of "search criteria" and use this varying "search criteria" as parameters in the Controller action method which constructs a viewmodel and gets the results from a method of the viewmodel by ultimately passing the 'user inputs' as parameters to that method's {Low level} `.FindAll()`.  Need the ability for user to use one or many or all inputs as their search criteria.  For example: User wants to search for Titles which have "John" as [CustFName]. Another example: User wants to search for Titles which have both "John" as [CustFName] and "Holmes" as [CustLName].

```
public class SearchTitleViewModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public SearchTitleViewModel()
        {
            var tits = _db.Titles.ToList();
        }

        public Title Title { get; set; }
        public List<Title> Titles { get; set; }

        public SearchTitleViewModel GetTitlesWithSearchCriteria(string office, bool? mv = null, int id = -1, string custFName = null, string custLName = null, string vin = null)
        {
            SearchTitleViewModel searchtitlevm = new SearchTitleViewModel();

            if (id > -1)
            {
                searchtitlevm.Title = _db.Titles.Find(id);
                searchtitlevm.Titles.Add(searchtitlevm.Title);

                return searchtitlevm;
            }

            searchtitlevm.Titles.AddRange(
                Titles.FindAll(
                    tit => tit.CustFName == custFName && // want to make "tit.CustFName == custFName" a variable
                           tit.CustLName == custLName &&// want to make "tit.CustFName == custFName" a variable
                           tit.InitialLocation == office
                )
            );

            return searchtitlevm;
        }
    }
```

Ultimately I would like to pass in multiple lambda expressions to `.FindAll()` as variables that are declared at runtime like `FindAll(Title tit, param1 custFNameExpression, param2 custLNameExpression, ...)` but have not been able to find any examples to do something like this.  I did find examples of creating a `delegate[]` but still does not solve the issue of adding an expression or not based on if the user supplied that one or not from the view.

Am I going about this all wrong?  I mean is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to make .FindAll() work for what I needed.  I used .SqlQuery() instead:

```
public class SearchTitleViewModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public SearchTitleViewModel()
    {
        Title = new Title()
        {
            NtyId = 1//for testing REMOVE
        };
        Titles = new List<Title>();
    }

    public Title Title { get; set; }
    public List<Title> Titles { get; set; }

    public SearchTitleViewModel GetTitlesWithSearchCriteria(SearchTitleViewModel vm)
    {
        var searchtitlevm = new SearchTitleViewModel();

        if (vm.Title.TitleNum != null)
        {
            searchtitlevm.Title = _db.Titles.Find(vm.Title.TitleNum);
            if (searchtitlevm.Title != null && searchtitlevm.Title.NtyId != vm.Title.NtyId)
            {
                return searchtitlevm;
            }

            searchtitlevm.Titles.Add(searchtitlevm.Title);                
            return searchtitlevm;
        }

        var titssql = "SELECT * FROM Titles WHERE";
        if (vm.Title.Vin != null) { titssql += $" Vin = \'{vm.Title.Vin}\' AND "; }
        if (vm.Title.CustLName != null) { titssql += $" CustLName = \'{vm.Title.CustLName}\' AND "; }
        if (vm.Title.CustFName != null) { titssql += $" CustFName = \'{vm.Title.CustFName}\' AND "; }
        titssql += $" NtyId = \'{vm.Title.NtytyId}\'";

        searchtitlevm.Titles = _db.Titles.SqlQuery(titssql).ToList();

        return searchtitlevm;
    }
}
```